# C# Regex and a bulk replace

Tags: c#, regex, string

There are several occurences of ab:tag_x tag in a string.

Tag format:

```
<ab:tag_x contents="some text" src_id="some id">
```

How can I replace each tag with the value of one of its attributes - 'contents'?

Examples:

```
<ab:tag_x contents="some text1" src_id="some id"> -> some text1
<ab:tag_x contents="some text2" src_id="some id"> -> some text2
```

Thanks,
LG

Comment: If this is XML, your requested replacement is not: you're not replacing the matching closing tag. If this is not XML, please explain in what ways it differs. For example, do any characters have a special meaning that you'd have to take into account?

Comment: @hvd There is a large chunk of non-xml/non-html text that contains several <ab:tag_x ...> tags. They need to be replaced with tag's 'contents' attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need some polishing, but here's what I got.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string data = "<data><ab:tag_x contents=\"some text1\" src_id=\"some id\"><br/><ab:tag_x contents=\"some text2\" src_id=\"some id\"></data>";
        string pattern = "<ab:tag_x.*?contents=\"(.*?)\".*?>";
        string replacement = "$1";
        string result = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, replacement);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

To understand how pattern works or modify it, read this MSDN on [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

To understand how replacement string works or modify it, read this MSDN on [Regular Expressions Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(myhtml, 
  "<ab:tagx[^>]+contents=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>\", 
  "$1");
```

This will handle:

- Any number of attributes before the `contents` attribute
- Any number of attributes after the `contents` attribute
- Start tags or self-closing tags
- Blank contents (`contents=""`)
- LF characters inside the tag (which is why I didn't use `.*?`).

Assumptions:

- Attribute values are delimited with double-quote characters.
- There are no whitespace characters around the equal sign.
- Tags and the `contents` attribute are always lowercase.
- Every tag contains the `contents` attribute, even if the value is blank.